# Image search engine use

Tags: ios, image, search, embed

is it possible to instantiate the use of an image search engine within an app? I have an idea to incorporate image search engines with the pictures that can be taken with the camera and then have the app return info about the picture that is recognized.

Comment: I would use an API, as opposed to writing your own if you're talking about a visual search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We offer an image search engine for mobile app cameras - www.iqengines.com.

Comment: So you are saying we.  Are you part of the IQ engines team.  I had previously reviewed your site and I am interested in finding out some more info about it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Goggles, Like.com (formerly Riya) now acquired by Google, Tineye.com are some sites that offer visual search. Not sure they offer an API.

If you want to whip one up, it is as you would expect, no trivial task. AFAIK, there are no OOTB solutions available: especially, considering your use-case of taking an image and getting related information (known in the trade parlance as [RST invariant template matching](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=rst%20invariance&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rst%20invariance)) - and you would need to look into significant investment of time and $.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer.  Beginning xcoder here and just trying to feel out if my ideas are within grasp.

Comment: Your idea isn't far out, in fact it is a popular sport :-) It is technically feasible, but like I said would take significant investment.